# Map labels are smaller in exported image than in print composer

Tags: qgis, export

I am trying to export images with legible town name sizes but they keep shrinking to an unreadable size when I export them. I have tried a few solutions based on similar questions but to no avail.

I am using QGIS version 2.18.9 and a number of different map sources (OSM, SIX, Google, Bing).

[image: Print Composer]

[image: Exported Image]

Comment: Could you throw in a few screenshots?

Comment: Just added a before and after.

Comment: Is the before from the Layout manager, or from QGIS?

Comment: what is the source of your basemap?

Comment: @Alex Leith: The before is from QGIS' Print Composer.

Comment: @Ian Turton: That particular basemap is NSW LPI Basemap (http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Base_Map/MapServer&ppi=320), but as mentioned in my original question this effect is occurring for ALL basemaps, INCLUDING QuickMapServices.